# How to iterate single JSON array result in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin

I am working for an Android Kotlin project to receive data from Http request.

The data return back from server is

**{ "Status": "Success" }**

and I want to retrieve this result in Android screen or console.

I tried the following code but the system is saying the string cannot be converted to JSONArray.

```
//Code for retrieve data from server
val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
val result = response.body?.string().toString()

//code to iterate json
val data = StringBuilder()
val resultArray = JSONArray(result)
 for (i in 0 until resultArray.length()){
  val jsonObject = resultArray.getJSONObject(i)
  val status = jsonObject.optString("Status")
  data.append(status)
}
textView.setText("Status" + data.toString())
println("Status" + data.toString())
```

Please check my code and suggests me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: the highest level element here is a JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Code for retrieve data from server
val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
val result = response.body?.string().toString()

//code to iterate json
val data = JSONObject(result) as JSONObject
val dataStatus = data.getString("Status")

println("$dataStatus")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JSONObject` to read the `response`

```
val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
val result = response.body?.string().toString()

//code to iterate json
val data = StringBuilder()
val statusObject = JSONObject(result)
textView.setText("Status${statusObject.optString("Status")}")
println("Status${statusObject.optString("Status")}")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to transform Json to Kotlin Data class. You can use this [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-) to generate a Kotlin data class from JSON Structure. And use GSON or Moshi library to parse json data to Kotlin data class. Then you can easily use Kotlin data class object to access any data in the response.